# What component is best for a voltage follower amp (specs given in question)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-electronics

I am wanting an op amp that can act as a voltage follower. Essentially the project is speed control of a motor and since PWM is being used, the following circuit was going to be implemented: Essentially just a RC filter to get the analogue signal, then a voltage follower so that the motor can draw the required current it needs since the arduino can only output say 20mA.
[image]
**(Ignore the output 1k resistor**)

As i do not know that much about opamps and what to look for for when choosing them, i was wondering if i could get some suggestions or even possibly a standard op amp that will work?

The supply to the op amp will be 5V, and preferably a component from Jaycar due to the time limit?

The input voltage to the opamp will be roughly always less then 4.5V
**The motor roughly draws 0.2 - 0.3A** 
Motor:
[image]

Comment: How much current does your motor draw? With the schematic you've shared, we're going to assume 5 V / 1 kohm = 5 mA.

Comment: The motor roughly draws 0.2 - 0.3A

Comment: Is that rated current or starting/braking current?

Comment: What is the motor voltage rating and DC resistance?

Comment: If you already have a PWM signal, then why not just hook it straight into an H-bridge (very efficient)? Why convert PWM -> Analog -> op-amp (very **in**efficient)?

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75, i added the motor spec sheet

Comment: @Harry Svensson, for a H-Bridge isnt that primarily used for switching motors (as in going forward then bacwards). The task is just to control the motor to run constantly at 12000rpm. A mosfet was going to be implemented also but is it not bad having a h bridge or mosfet since for example with the motor, if the pwm signal was say for example high for 0.2 seconds and 0.8 seconds low, couldnt the motor potentially be pretty bad at speed control compared to a constant voltage signal (which is achieved through the rc filter)

Comment: Here’s a half bridge http://tinyurl.com/y4le5a7c. Duplicate this for the other side but with inverted clock (PWM) to get stop at 50% and directional control. Use power transistors

Comment: @Student PWM with a 1 second period (=1 Hz) is **very low**, shouldn't you be in the kHz range? If you use PWM in the kHz range then the motor itself will act as a low pass filter, it already has inductive elements behaving like a low pass filter, also its rotor acts as yet another low pass element. - I know that a guy called "Andy Aka" made a good H-bridge design, [this is my attempt at remaking it from memory](http://tinyurl.com/y2o3hvyr). If Andy ever sees this... sorry for not making it as good as you did it. Forgive me.

Comment: Sorry @Harry that was just a example, the frequency is around 400Hz

Comment: @Student Depending on whatever your load is and the size of the motor, it might be okay, though you'll definitely hear a 400 Hz hum. But then again, there is a motor running, so you're already creating noise, some extra hum shouldn't bother you. Though, I'd try to push that frequency up by a factor of 10 or 100 if I were you.

Comment: What is a hum mean in terms of noise? Also, whats the main difference between using an H bridge and just one mosfet that switches the motor?

Comment: @Student [This is what 400 Hz hum sounds like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_7__fCayzs). [This is how an electric motor kinda sounds like](https://youtu.be/YSOpl4gG95w?t=10). I am implying that you won't be bothered by the 400 Hz hum when you have a motor running. - Using an H-bridge instead of only one mosfet has the strength of allowing the current to flow in low-resistance paths, and that the back-emf gets clamped with yet again, low-resistance components. - But then again, I'm slightly overpendantic, it's obvious that your motor is small, so you shouldn't put too much thought into it.